# pyinstaller cannot see configparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, configparser

I am using configparser in a python application

When I run the application

```
python main.py
```

it works. However if I use pyinstall to create a windows exe, the exe fails with the message

```
no module named 'configparser'
```

however as the screen shot shows, configparser does exist

What is going on here?

NB I do NOT get  the error if I remove __init__.py from the directory

[image]

[More info]

This seems to be a 'sys.path' issue. If I copy configparser.py into my application directory, the problem moves on to another module that I'm calling

Should I change my pyinstaller spec file?

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
a.datas = list({tuple(map(str.upper, t)) for t in a.datas})
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='test_imports.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True)
```

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

Answer (score 4):

I also had this issue. In my case, it was a hidden import and was fixed with the --hidden-import option.

`$ pyinstaller my_script.py --hidden-import=configparser`

Comment: Thanks Ian. can the option be added to the script?

Comment: @Psionman There is a `hiddenimports` parameter on the `Analysis` object in your spec file. I haven't tested that it works in the same way though. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks.I'll give it a go

Comment: This did not work for me for ConfigArgParse

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by removing __init__.py from root directory